# Script not working on my element

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have script that is not working in my wordpress site, but it used to be working before I had my pc reset. I can't find the error in these lines, maybe the problem is another, don't really know. The only suggest is `Eslint teminated with error:timeout` from brackets debug... It used to work unless, I don't know if I modified it and ended up making some mistake, my knowledge is kinda obsolete since it's been a while and I'm refreshing...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 // define variables
    var navOffset, scrollPos = 0;

 // add utility wrapper elements for positioning
 jQuery(".blog-nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');

 // function to run on page load and window resize
 function stickyUtility() {

  // only update navOffset if it is not currently using fixed position
  if (jQuery(".blog-nav").hasClass("fixed")) {
   navOffset = jQuery(".blog-nav").offset().top;
  }

  // apply matching height to nav wrapper div to avoid awkward content jumps
  jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery(".blog-nav").outerHeight());

 } // end stickyUtility function

 // run on page load
 stickyUtility();

 // run on window resize
 jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  stickyUtility();
 });

 // run on scroll event
 jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

  scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
   jQuery(".blog-nav").addClass("fixed");
  } else {
   jQuery(".blog-nav").removeClass("fixed");
  }

 });

});
```

```css
.blog-nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #000000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

div.blog nav li {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

nav.blog-nav li a:link,
nav.blog-nav li a:visited {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 50px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

div.blog a:visited,
div.blog a:link {
 color: #000000;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.space {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog" id="blog" name="blog">
<nav class="blog-nav">
   <li><a href="#blog">Notizie</a></li>
  </nav>
    <div class="space"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error with my jquery code in wordpress. code it works fine but when I upload site online stop working

- First check your functions file in php and make sure that you include jquery in head

`function my_enqueue_scripts() {wp_enqueue_script('jquery');}`

- make sure that jquery file required above every js file

Comment: Problem is it was working when I had my pc on ubuntu, but now that I returned to windows it is not working anymore, but as far as I know it should read jQuery by default anyways